# Unity, how find my game object and move it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm totally newbie with Unity and C# and i try to do a 3D game.

I want to when i press "Qkey", the cube descends in height.

here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class ripcube : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    bool isTeleported = false;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("a") && !isTeleported)
        {
            ripcube.transform.position = (-2, -2, -2) ;
        }

    }

}
```

And it gives me the error:

```
(19,13): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Component.transform'
```

I know than ripcube is my class, but what is my gameobject? i created my cube on the graphics interface..

Thanks for your help

Comment: remove the `ripcube.` ... and then use `transform.position = new Vector3(-2, -2, -2);` or `transform.position = Vector3.one * -2;` .. so basically using `this.transform`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that was only that,  you can add this answers if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go watch some basic videos on youtube on how unity gameobjects work but for now:

You can reference game objects from your code or find them as following:

```
public class ripcube: MonoBehaviour 
{
    GameObject myCubeObject;
    float speed = 2f;

    void Start() 
    {
        myCubeObject = GameObject.Find("YourCubeNameInUnity");
    }        

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            myCubeObject.transform.Translate(speed * Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Thing you should notice here :

1. The GameObject is a Unity class that is the base for all the game objects in the scene,
   you can find it by its name in the Hierarchy view.
2. After you find it you can access it in the Update() function and change its transform every frame.
3. Here I used Translate wich is an addition to the position every frame
4. you can also use `myCubeObject.transform.position += speed * Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime`
5. Be aware that im using a `float speed` variable that is the speed the cube will go in the desired direction (I used 2 for the value but it can be anything really).
6. The direction is specified by a vector (`Vector3.down`). You can change is as you please
7. Multiplying by Time.deltaTime makes the movement independant on FPS (Frames per second) wich is determined normally bt the machine the game is running on.

Answer (score 2):

bro you can use

```
transform.position = new Vector3(-2, -2, -2);
```

instead of

```
transform.position = (-2, -2, -2) ;
```

and change

```
Input.GetKey("a")
```

to

```
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)
```